# Loop that adds user inputted numbers and breaks when user types "end"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Create a function that expects no arguments. The function asks user to enter a series of numbers greater than or equal to zero, one at a time. The user types end to indicate that there are no more numbers. The function computes the sum of all the values entered.

I'm supposed to be able to do this with just while loops and if statements.

The main issue I'm running into is that I don't know how to make it so that "end" actually stops the loop, rather than add to the value.

```
def SumFunction():
"""Sum of all values entered"""

number = 0
while number >= 0 and number is not "end":
    number = number + (float(input("Enter next number: ")))
return number
```

Answer (score 1):

Split up the loop into more discrete steps:

```
def SumFunction():
    """Sum of all values entered"""
    number = 0
    user_input = 1
    while user_input >= 0:
        user_input = input("Enter next number: ")
        if user_input == 'end':
            break
        user_input = float(user_input)
        number += max(user_input, 0)
    return number
```

This first gets user input and checks if it's `'end'`. If it is, the program breaks out of the loop and returns the running total, `number`. If it isn't, the program converts the user input to a number and adds it to `number`. If the number is 0 or negative, the program will add nothing to `number`, and the loop will stop. Finally, the resulting `number` is returned.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't if the function you made was supposed to work or not, but I'm getting errors with it. Im running into the same type of problem that I had in the beginning. I don't know how to make it so the program can differentiate between the float numbers and the string value of "end" to terminate. Burhan was on the right track with his thinking, but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what your loop is checking for:

> "Do this, while the number is greater than or equal to 0 and it is not 'end'`.

Which value satisfies both conditions? If I enter `'end'` then does it satisfy both criteria; because your loop will only break if both conditions are true.

So you really want *`or`* not *`and`*.

Once you solve that issue, you'll run into another problem:

```
>>> def sum_function():
...     number = 0
...     while number >= 0 or number is not 'end':
...         number = number + float(input('Enter a number: '))
...     return number
... 
>>> sum_function()
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in sum_function
ValueError: could not convert string to float: end
```

The problem here is that you are converting everything to a float immediately after its entered; so as soon as someone enters `'end'`, your program crashes because it cannot convert `'end'` to a float.

Try to solve that one yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a try catch, if there is a `Value Error` when you are looking for a number they probably typed end, non the less you can do the apropriate checking in the except block.

Answer (score -1):

This program is what you want I guess:

```
def SumFunction():
    sum = 0
    while(True):
        x = input('Enter: ')
        while x.lower()=='end':
            return sum
        while float(x) >= 0:
            sum += float(x)
            break
        else:
            print ("Wrong Number!")
```

Output:

```
>>> SumFunction()
Enter: 1
Enter: 2
Enter: -1
Wrong Number!
Enter: end
3.0
>>>
```

*You can use `break` in a loop to go out of it. You can also use `return` method to exit of a function. When you went out of a function, you also went out of the loop!*

*The else block for a loop runs if and only if the loop is exited normally (i.e., without hitting a break).*

Comment: This doesn't match all the requirements of the assignment.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Corrected. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks Ebrahim. Is the raw_input function in Python 2? I'm learning how to code with python 3, so I'm not too familiar with that function sorry. Is there a python 3 alternative?

Comment: @sluh I modified the answer to work with Python3. The `input()` method in Python 3 works fine instead of `raw_input()` of Python 2. Moreover, `print` methods need `()` in Python 3.

Comment: @sluh You may want to accept my answer as corrected answer by checking the tick mark at the left side of my answer. :)